# Calling an external function with redux-saga yield call appears to give context errors

Tags: redux, this, redux-saga

I have a `redux-saga` watcher/saga setup as below:

```
function* parseSaga(action) {

  let result = corewar.parser.parse(action.redcode)

  yield put({ type: PARSE, result })

}

export function* parseWatcher() {  
  yield takeLatest(PARSE_REQUESTED, parseSaga);
}
```

Where `corewar` is an imported `npm` package I've written.

When the function is written as above, it works as expected, but I'd like to wrap the call to `parse` in a `yield call` so that I can better test things as described in the docs here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html

However, when I wrap up the function call like so:

```
let result = yield call(corewar.parser.parse, action.redcode)
```

I get an error which appears to come from my npm package as follows:

```
uncaught at parseWatcher at parseWatcher 
 at takeLatest 
 at parseSaga 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'scanner' of null
    at Parser.parse (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2017:28)
    at runCallEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43679:19)
    at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43601:648)
    ... and so on
```

Scanner in this case is an internal property to the `Parser` class which is called in the `parse` method as shown below (in typescript):

```
public parse(document: string, options?: IParseOptions): IParseResult {

    options = Object.assign({}, Parser.DefaultOptions, options || {});

    var context = this.scanner.scan(document, options);

    ... other stuff

}
```

So it appears like somehow through using this saga it's got inside my `npm` package and messed up the `this` reference?

It seems like I need to somehow ensure the previous context is retained but I wasn't sure how to achieve this as I'm not aware of how it's become lost by just wrapping the external call up in the `redux-saga` `call` function.

**EDIT: The plot thickens**

So it's definitely a context issue, but it seems related to calling nested function calls. I've tweaked the `npm` package so that `parse` is also exposed from the root object and now see the following results:

**Works**

```
let result = yield call(corewar.parse.bind(corewar), action.redcode)
let result = yield call([corewar, corewar.parse], action.redcode)
```

but the original nested method does not

**Does not work**

```
let result = yield call(corewar.parser.parse.bind(corewar), action.redcode)
let result = yield call([corewar, corewar.parser.parse], action.redcode)
```

I'm willing to expose the public interface from the root object (as it was on my todo list anyway) but is this the expected result? or some quirk?

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this working

```
let result = yield call(corewar.parser.parse.bind(corewar.parser), action.redcode)
```

Since `parse` is a method of `coreware.parser` and not just `coreware`.

If this is not working then why not:

```
const parse = code => corewar.parser.parse(code);

let result = yield call(parse, action.redcode)
```

Comment: I didn't go as far as to bind that deep as tbh I don't fully understand at this moment why saga's seem to be stealing the scope and I'd like to find out a bit more before making too many changes.
You're second example seems syntatically nicer to me, and I do control the API of the `corewar` package so could expose those functions in that way. Thing is, the original functions are written in Typescript and should already be wrapped up in modules, so as per my original point, unsure how redux-saga has got it mitts on the scope

Comment: Facing the same issue. Thanks for the idea, using bind solved the issue.